# SQL DimCalendar dynamic fiscal week for calendar 5-4-4

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, business-intelligence

My aims is to create a 5-4-4 calendar where my Accounting starting period = '2019-04-01' and ending period = '2020-03-31'
 My Fiscal Week should start from Week 1 to Week 52.
 Below is my SQL query which display my accounting calendar

```
DECLARE @START_DATE DATE
DECLARE @END_DATE DATE
DECLARE @COUNTER INT

SET @START_DATE = '2019-04-01'
SET @END_DATE = '2020-03-31'
SET @COUNTER = 1

DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(
  CALENDAR_DATE DATE,
  WEEK_NUM INTEGER,
  START_WEEK DATE,
  END_WEEK DATE
)

WHILE @START_DATE <= @END_DATE
BEGIN 

SET DATEFIRST 4

INSERT INTO @TABLE (CALENDAR_DATE,START_WEEK,END_WEEK)

SELECT 
 @START_DATE,
 DATEADD(dd, 0 - (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @START_DATE)) % 7, @START_DATE),
 DATEADD(dd, 6 - (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @START_DATE)) % 7, @START_DATE) Sunday

SET @START_DATE = DATEADD(day, 1, @START_DATE)
SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1

END

SELECT DISTINCT 
  START_WEEK,
  END_WEEK,
  CASE 
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-04-01' AND END_WEEK = '2019-04-07' THEN 'WEEK 1' 
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-04-08' AND END_WEEK = '2019-04-14' THEN 'WEEK 2' 
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-04-15' AND END_WEEK = '2019-04-21' THEN 'WEEK 3' 
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-04-22' AND END_WEEK = '2019-04-28' THEN 'WEEK 4' 
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-04-29' AND END_WEEK = '2019-05-05' THEN 'WEEK 5' 
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-05-06' AND END_WEEK = '2019-05-12' THEN 'WEEK 6' 
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-05-13' AND END_WEEK = '2019-05-19' THEN 'WEEK 7' 
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-05-20' AND END_WEEK = '2019-05-26' THEN 'WEEK 8' 
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-05-27' AND END_WEEK = '2019-06-02' THEN 'WEEK 9'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-06-03' AND END_WEEK = '2019-06-09' THEN 'WEEK 10'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-06-10' AND END_WEEK = '2019-06-16' THEN 'WEEK 11'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-06-17' AND END_WEEK = '2019-06-23' THEN 'WEEK 12'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-06-24' AND END_WEEK = '2019-06-30' THEN 'WEEK 13'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-07-01' AND END_WEEK = '2019-07-07' THEN 'WEEK 14'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-07-08' AND END_WEEK = '2019-07-14' THEN 'WEEK 15'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-07-15' AND END_WEEK = '2019-07-21' THEN 'WEEK 16'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-07-22' AND END_WEEK = '2019-07-28' THEN 'WEEK 17'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-07-29' AND END_WEEK = '2019-08-04' THEN 'WEEK 18'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-08-05' AND END_WEEK = '2019-08-11' THEN 'WEEK 19'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-08-12' AND END_WEEK = '2019-08-18' THEN 'WEEK 20'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-08-19' AND END_WEEK = '2019-08-25' THEN 'WEEK 21'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-08-26' AND END_WEEK = '2019-09-01' THEN 'WEEK 22'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-09-02' AND END_WEEK = '2019-09-08' THEN 'WEEK 23'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-09-09' AND END_WEEK = '2019-09-15' THEN 'WEEK 24'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-09-16' AND END_WEEK = '2019-09-22' THEN 'WEEK 25'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-09-23' AND END_WEEK = '2019-09-29' THEN 'WEEK 26'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-09-30' AND END_WEEK = '2019-10-06' THEN 'WEEK 27'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-10-07' AND END_WEEK = '2019-10-13' THEN 'WEEK 28'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-10-14' AND END_WEEK = '2019-10-20' THEN 'WEEK 29'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-10-21' AND END_WEEK = '2019-10-27' THEN 'WEEK 30'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-10-28' AND END_WEEK = '2019-11-03' THEN 'WEEK 31'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-11-04' AND END_WEEK = '2019-11-10' THEN 'WEEK 32'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-11-11' AND END_WEEK = '2019-11-17' THEN 'WEEK 33'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-11-18' AND END_WEEK = '2019-11-24' THEN 'WEEK 34'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-11-25' AND END_WEEK = '2019-12-01' THEN 'WEEK 35'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-12-02' AND END_WEEK = '2019-12-08' THEN 'WEEK 36'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-12-09' AND END_WEEK = '2019-12-15' THEN 'WEEK 37'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-12-16' AND END_WEEK = '2019-12-22' THEN 'WEEK 38'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-12-23' AND END_WEEK = '2019-12-29' THEN 'WEEK 39'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2019-12-30' AND END_WEEK = '2020-01-05' THEN 'WEEK 40'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2020-01-06' AND END_WEEK = '2020-01-12' THEN 'WEEK 41'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2020-01-13' AND END_WEEK = '2020-01-19' THEN 'WEEK 42'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2020-01-20' AND END_WEEK = '2020-01-26' THEN 'WEEK 43'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2020-01-27' AND END_WEEK = '2020-02-02' THEN 'WEEK 44'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2020-02-03' AND END_WEEK = '2020-02-09' THEN 'WEEK 45'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2020-02-10' AND END_WEEK = '2020-02-16' THEN 'WEEK 46'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2020-02-17' AND END_WEEK = '2020-02-23' THEN 'WEEK 47'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2020-02-24' AND END_WEEK = '2020-03-01' THEN 'WEEK 48'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2020-03-02' AND END_WEEK = '2020-03-08' THEN 'WEEK 49'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2020-03-09' AND END_WEEK = '2020-03-15' THEN 'WEEK 50'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2020-03-16' AND END_WEEK = '2020-03-22' THEN 'WEEK 51'
    WHEN START_WEEK = '2020-03-23' AND END_WEEK = '2020-03-29' THEN 'WEEK 52'
  END AS FY_WEEK
 FROM @TABLE
 ORDER BY START_WEEK,END_WEEK;
```

My problem is the Fiscal Week (FY_WEEK) column, I don't want to hard-code those START_WEEK and END_WEEK value.

I'm looking for a way where I can dynamically populate my fiscal week column instead of hardcoding values.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  START_WEEK,
  END_WEEK,
    DATEDIFF(WEEK,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, START_WEEK) BETWEEN 4 AND 12 THEN DATEPART(YEAR, START_WEEK) ELSE DATEPART(YEAR, START_WEEK)-1 END)+'0401',
        START_WEEK
    )+1 AS 'FY_WEEK'
 FROM @TABLE
 ORDER BY START_WEEK,END_WEEK;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did only few changes in your code:

```
DECLARE @START_DATE DATE
DECLARE @END_DATE DATE
DECLARE @COUNTER INT
SET @START_DATE = '2019-04-01'
SET @END_DATE = '2020-03-31'
SET @COUNTER = 1

DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(
 CALENDAR_DATE DATE,WEEK_NUM INTEGER,START_WEEK DATE,
  END_WEEK DATE
  )

 WHILE @START_DATE <= @END_DATE
 BEGIN 
 SET DATEFIRST 4
 INSERT INTO @TABLE (CALENDAR_DATE,START_WEEK,END_WEEK)

 SELECT  @START_DATE,
 DATEADD(dd, 0 - (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @START_DATE)) % 7, @START_DATE),
 DATEADD(dd, 6 - (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @START_DATE)) % 7, @START_DATE) 
 Sunday
 SET @START_DATE = DATEADD(day, 1, @START_DATE)
 SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1
 END
 select DISTINCT  START_WEEK,  END_WEEK
 into #temp FROM @TABLE
 ORDER BY START_WEEK,END_WEEK;
```

and run

```
  `select * ,concat( 'week',ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY START_WEEK)) row_num from 
  #temp`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `recursive cte` (as below shown in below query) or `tally` table without the temp table / table variable

```
DECLARE @START_DATE DATE
DECLARE @END_DATE DATE

SET @START_DATE = '2019-04-01'
SET @END_DATE = '2020-03-31'

-- Change the start date to the `Monday` of the week
SELECT  @START_DATE = DATEADD(DAY, 
                            - (@@DATEFIRST+ DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @START_DATE) - 1 + 6) % 7, 
                              @START_DATE)

; WITH CTE as
(
    SELECT  START_WEEK = @START_DATE, END_WEEK = DATEADD(DAY, 6, @START_DATE), 
            FY_WEEK = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  START_WEEK = DATEADD(DAY, 7, START_WEEK), END_WEEK = DATEADD(DAY, 7, END_WEEK), 
            FY_WEEK = FY_WEEK + 1
    FROM    CTE
    WHERE   DATEADD(DAY, 7, START_WEEK) <= @END_DATE
)
SELECT  *
FROM    CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 52)
```

this does not depends on the `DATEFIRST` settings